# List view error. OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate

Tags: android, listview

I was trying to make a listview populate using the files in my internal storage but I keep getting an error every time I do. Here are my codes:

```
public class ReminderListActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE = 0;
    ListView listSavedFiles;
    String[] SavedFiles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_reminder_list);
        listSavedFiles = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sampleList);
        ShowSavedFiles();
    }

    void ShowSavedFiles() {
        SavedFiles = getApplicationContext().fileList();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter
                = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                SavedFiles);

        listSavedFiles.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16000012 byte allocation 
with 4194304 free bytes and 14MB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:836)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2068)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2048)
at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:155)
at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:184)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2071)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2048)
at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:155)
at com.android.systemui.recents.misc.SystemServicesProxy.getActivityIcon(SystemServicesProxy.java:494)
at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:407)
at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.executePlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:238)
at com.android.systemui.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.loadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:477)
at com.android.systemui.recents.Recents$TaskStackListenerImpl.run(Recents.java:142)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I dont even have any files thats taking up memory

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:onClick="onClickSave"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="465dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sampleList"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what are you using for your activity's icon?

Comment: a custom icon but it should only be 70kb big

Comment: Note the `BitmapFactory` in your stacktrace. Without seeing the rest of your project, I would assume that there are some images somewhere that your emulator can't process. (I'm assuming you are using an emulator since I most frequently see this error on emulators.)

Comment: the stack trace seems to imply it's a problem with the icon, make sure you have the icons in the best directories for their sizes